# list all students who have written atmost one exam per day

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables likes Student,Subject,and Midterm tables.

Student table contains

```
studid Firstname lastname Class

1      A       R        12A
2      B       S        12A
3      C       T        12A
4      D       U        12A
5      E       V        12B
```

SUBJECT table contains

```
subid subname
  1     maths
  2     science
  3     english
```

MIDTERM table contains

```
studid subid marks examdate
1        1    100  2014-09-24
1        2     92  2014-09-25
1        2     92  2014-09-26
2        1     74  2014-09-24
2        2     78  2014-09-26
2        3     73  2014-09-26
3        1     90  2014-09-24
3        2     84  2014-09-25
3        2     92  2014-09-25
5        1     87  2014-09-24
4        2     79  2014-09-24
4        3     90  2014-09-26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Student

EXCEPT
--list of students with more than one subject per day

select A.* from Student A 
join
(select studid, examdate, count(distinct subid)cnt group by studid, examdate from [Midterm]
)B
on A.Studid = B.Studid
and B.cnt >1
```

Comment: No its not working.how can you use count without using group by and also the result must be Firstname,Lastname,subname,examdate

Comment: I tried this query but it shows the error

 select a.FirstName,a.LastName,b.SubName,t.ExamDate from 
 (select studid,ExamDate,subid from [StudentDetails].[dbo].[MidTermTable]
   group by studid,subid,ExamDate having count(subid)=1) T
    inner join  [StudentDetails].dbo.StudentTable a  on T.StudID=a.StudID
 inner join [StudentDetails].dbo.SubjectTable b on t.SubID=b.SubID

Comment: @Perumal -- (embarassed) it was syntactical error..fixed it now

Comment: The query which you wrote doesn't match your own requirements. You can get a list of students who wrote more than one subjects per day. But you cannt get the subjects in it. That would be a different query.

Comment: when i try to find the max(examdate)>2 it shows the error as
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with tinyint.

I gave the date datatype for examdate.how to convert it.

Comment: `MAX(examdate)` returns you a date. You can't compare it with a whole number. The expression should be `count(examdate) > 1`

Comment: when i try  to select students last  exam they took,if there is more than one exam list all.
select studid,MAX(examdate) as Examdate
      from [StudentDetails].dbo.[MidTermTable] group by studid having COUNT(examdate)>1, the result came,but when i join three tables it shows wrong results,  the result must be FirstName,Lastname,subname...plz help me